# Can I use both DevExpress and Telerik on the same web page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, devexpress

Will there be any problems if I use DevExpress controls and Telerik controls on the same web page.  Imagine I am nesting them insider one another.

I am wondering if they would conflict each other during AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use both of them. There is no conflict. Because web.config has different arguments about these controls.
Maybe page is much more slower. Devexpress is running slowly.

Comment: no, i just try them in same project (asp.net 4.0 web forms), it seem the visual style will conflict each other.